# pyspark pandas udf RuntimeError: Number of columns of the returned doesn't match specified schema

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

I have pandas udf defined below

```py
schema2 = StructType([   StructField('sensorid', IntegerType(), True),
    StructField('confidence', DoubleType(), True)]) 

@pandas_udf(schema2,  PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)   
def PreProcess(Indf):   
    confidence=1  
    sensor=Indf.iloc[0,0]   
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sensorid','confidence'])  
    df['sensorid']=[sensor]   
    df['confidence']=[0]   
    return df
```

I am then passing a spark dataframe with 3 columns into that udf

```
results.groupby("sensorid").apply(PreProcess)

results:
+--------+---------------+---------------+
|sensorid|sensortimestamp|calculatedvalue|
+--------+---------------+---------------+
|  397332|     1596518086|          -39.0|
|  397332|     1596525586|          -31.0|
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Number of columns of the returned pandas.DataFrame doesn't match specified schema.Expected: 3 Actual: 4
```

I can tell what the error is trying to say but I don't understand how this error can pop up. I thought I am returning the correct 2 columns of the dataframe specified in the struct

Comment: Also, I am running this in a databricks note book on a cluster.
Cluster info: 42GB | 12cores | DBR6.4 | spark 2.4.5

Comment: @tryingtocode Do you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

[`apply`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.apply.html) is deprecated and it seems that expects to return the same input columns, in this case 3. Try to use [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html?highlight=applyinpandas) with the expected output schema:

```py
results.groupby("sensorid").applyInPandas(PreProcess, schema=schema2)
```

Updated links with latest version. (Spark's doc change and links were broken)

In version 3.0.0: [`apply`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.apply) [`applyInPandas`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas)